# Group records by continuous date periods in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this:

| t104f005_employee_no | t104f040_position_no | t104f025_date_effective | t104f030_date_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11354 | 89043 | 01/07/1999 | 01/04/2012 |
| 11354 | 89043 | 02/04/2012 | 31/08/2014 |
| 11354 | 89043 | 01/09/2014 | 21/09/2014 |
| 11354 | 89043 | 22/09/2014 | 27/09/2015 |
| 11354 | 23273 | 04/05/2015 | 27/09/2015 |
| 11354 | 94040 | 28/09/2015 | 10/01/2016 |
| 11354 | 94040 | 11/01/2016 | 08/05/2017 |
| 11354 | 94040 | 09/05/2017 | 24/03/2019 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 26/02/2018 | 01/07/2018 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 02/07/2018 | 30/09/2018 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 01/10/2018 | 01/11/2018 |
| 11354 | 97293 | 02/11/2018 | 25/11/2018 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 26/11/2018 | 10/03/2019 |
| 11354 | 97293 | 11/03/2019 | 24/03/2019 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 25/03/2019 | 30/09/2019 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 01/10/2019 | 15/03/2020 |
| 11354 | 97293 | 11/11/2019 | 24/11/2019 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 16/03/2020 | 10/05/2020 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 11/05/2020 | 14/06/2020 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 11/05/2020 | 14/06/2020 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 15/06/2020 | 04/10/2020 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 15/06/2020 | 04/10/2020 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 05/10/2020 | 25/10/2020 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 05/10/2020 | 21/11/2021 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 26/10/2020 | 31/01/2021 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 01/02/2021 | 28/02/2021 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 01/03/2021 | 30/06/2021 |
| 11354 | 101806 | 01/07/2021 | 18/07/2021 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 19/07/2021 | 21/11/2021 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 22/11/2021 | 28/11/2021 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 22/11/2021 | 28/11/2021 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 29/11/2021 | 20/03/2022 |
| 11354 | 101806 | 21/03/2022 | 17/04/2022 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 21/03/2022 | 22/05/2022 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 23/05/2022 | 09/04/2023 |
| 11354 | 101903 | 15/08/2022 | 12/02/2023 |
| 11354 | 105009 | 13/02/2023 | 28/02/2023 |
| 11354 | 105009 | 01/03/2023 | 09/04/2023 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 10/04/2023 | NULL |
| 11354 | 80717 | 15/05/2023 | 12/05/2024 |

And I need to be able to identify the continuous position no periods with the min start and max end date outputted for each continuous period.  Expected outcome would look like this:

| t104f005_employee_no | t104f040_position_no | t104f025_date_effective | t104f030_date_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11354 | 89043 | 01/07/1999 | 27/09/2015 |
| 11354 | 23273 | 04/05/2015 | 27/09/2015 |
| 11354 | 94040 | 28/09/2015 | 24/03/2019 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 26/02/2018 | 01/11/2018 |
| 11354 | 97293 | 02/11/2018 | 25/11/2018 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 26/11/2018 | 10/03/2019 |
| 11354 | 97293 | 11/03/2019 | 24/03/2019 |
| 11354 | 99406 | 25/03/2019 | 28/11/2021 |
| 11354 | 97293 | 11/11/2019 | 24/11/2019 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 11/05/2020 | 30/06/2021 |
| 11354 | 101806 | 01/07/2021 | 18/07/2021 |
| 11354 | 101808 | 19/07/2021 | NULL |
| 11354 | 101806 | 21/03/2022 | 17/04/2022 |
| 11354 | 101903 | 15/08/2022 | 12/02/2023 |
| 11354 | 105009 | 13/02/2023 | 28/02/2023 |
| 11354 | 105009 | 01/03/2023 | 09/04/2023 |
| 11354 | 80717 | 15/05/2023 | 12/05/2024 |

I have tried the following methods but it's not working out and I'm a bit stumped now.

```
WITH RankedPositions AS (
  SELECT
    [t104f005_employee_no],
    [t104f040_position_no],
    [t104f025_date_effective],
    [t104f030_date_to],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [t104f005_employee_no] ORDER BY [t104f025_date_effective]) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [t104f005_employee_no], [t104f040_position_no] ORDER BY [t104f025_date_effective]) AS grp
  FROM [AUR11PROD].[dbo].[t104_employment_history] with (nolock)
  WHERE [t104f005_employee_no] = '11354'
)    
SELECT
  [t104f005_employee_no],
  [t104f040_position_no],
  MIN([t104f025_date_effective]) AS min_startdate,
  MAX([t104f030_date_to]) AS max_enddate
FROM RankedPositions
GROUP BY [t104f005_employee_no], [t104f040_position_no], grp
ORDER BY [t104f005_employee_no], min_startdate;
```

and this one

```
WITH RECURSIVE ContinuousPositions AS (
  SELECT
    employee_no,
    position_no,
    startdate,
    enddate
  FROM your_table_name
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM your_table_name AS t2
    WHERE t2.employee_no = your_table_name.employee_no
      AND t2.position_no = your_table_name.position_no
      AND t2.startdate < your_table_name.startdate
  )
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    cp.employee_no,
    cp.position_no,
    cp.startdate,
    t.enddate
  FROM ContinuousPositions AS cp
  JOIN your_table_name AS t ON (
    cp.employee_no = t.employee_no
    AND cp.position_no = t.position_no
    AND cp.enddate = DATEADD(day, -1, t.startdate)
  )
)    
SELECT
  employee_no,
  position_no,
  MIN(startdate) AS min_startdate,
  MAX(enddate) AS max_enddate
FROM ContinuousPositions
GROUP BY employee_no, position_no
ORDER BY employee_no, min_startdate;
```

Comment: have you tried window function?

Comment: @BagusTesa yep tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem. One way is to use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to identify when the continuous date break and set a flag (`g`). Performing a cumulative sum() on the flag gives you the required grouping (`grp`).

```
with 
cte as
(
    select employee_no, position_no, date_effective, date_expiry,
           g = case when dateadd(day, -1, date_effective)
                    <>   lag(date_expiry) over (partition by employee_no, position_no
                                                    order by date_effective)
                    then 1
                    else 0
                    end
    from   employment_history
),
cte2 as
(
   select employee_no, position_no, date_effective, 
          date_expiry = isnull(date_expiry, '99991231'), 
          grp = sum(g) over (partition by employee_no, position_no
                                 order by date_effective)  
    from  cte
)
select employee_no, position_no, 
       date_effective = min(date_effective), 
       date_expiry    = nullif(max(date_expiry), '99991231')
from   cte2
group by employee_no, position_no, grp
order by employee_no, date_effective
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UGGqu8Q8)

Comment: Hey @squirrel, thank you!  I tried this but I am getting this error.  Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Column "cte2.t104f025_date_effective" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
I am on this version - Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5021129) - 13.0.6430.49 (X64) 
 Jan 22 2023 17:38:22 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: I am not using the exact same column name as yours as my brain can't process those additional `t104...` prefix. Just compare the DDL and do a  find and replace with your actual column name, it will work

Comment: Cheers @squirrell.  I must have edited something incorrectly the 1st time round.

Comment: @DaleK - I did, still learning.